# Do enclosed switching power supplies follow any standard for their chassis size and mounting hole distances?

Tags: power-supply, standard, enclosure, dimensions, mounting-holes

Do [enclosed switching power supplies](https://uk.farnell.com/c/power-line-protection/power-supplies/ac-dc-converters/ac-dc-enclosed-power-supplies) follow any standard for their chassis size and mounting holes distances?
or each manufacturer has its own conventions?

Comment: There are a multitude of chassis shapes and sizes with a plethora of mounting options. That said, there are some standards out there which are followed - PC ATX power supplies have standard width/height and mounting holes, for instance. Some manufactures produce 1U-height 54mm and 86mm-wide power supplies with blind-mate connectors which allow for system integrators to use power supplies from different vendors as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not generally no, they don't have the same sizes or mounting patterns. On occasion some companies will match the mounting pattern and size to compete directly with a power supply. An exception to this is industry standard supplies like ATX or supplies that are built for 1U chassis ect.

It's a good idea to put a power supply on a bracket that attaches to a chassis in the event the power supply needs to be switched in a product. (I've had a few  power supplies blow up and we had to find a replacement, and because we had a bracket we could make them field serviceable)